# Disable UI in my Activity when user places the phone near his/her ear?

Tags: android

How can I disable my UI of my activity when user place the phone near his/her ear?

I know there is an API which get a call back when there is a sensor to test for Proximity:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html

But how can I disable UI (like user's face won't mistakenly as UI touching) and then re-enable back when the phone is further away from User's face?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at the [`PhoneApp`](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_phone/blob/gingerbread-release/src/com/android/phone/PhoneApp.java) and [`InCallScreen`](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_phone/blob/gingerbread-release/src/com/android/phone/InCallScreen.java) source code from AOSP for some ideas on how to do what you want. Here are the main points:

- On devices that support it, the AOSP code utilize the hidden `PowerManager.PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK` to turn off the touchscreen as needed (see the `PhoneApp.updateProximitySensorMode()` method).
- On other devices, the approach is to use a "touch lock" overlay (simply showing/hiding a View covering the whole screen which will consume the touch events). See `initTouchLock()`, `enableTouchLock()` and `onTouch()` methods in the `InCallScreen` source (code dealing with `mTouchLockOverlay` mostly).

I would recommend using the overlay approach since it will work on all devices.

Depending on your UI hierarchy, using an overlay might also be better compared to toggling the touch and visibility state of your normal UI since it is simpler to implement and you can add some visual feedback very easily (dimming/animation maybe?) while the overlay is shown.

Comment: I fixed the broken links by pointing to gingerbread release branch (the current version around the time the answer was posted).

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few ways off the top of my head:

you could call

```
view.setClickable(false);
```

On all of your UI elements. I don't know for sure but you might be able to call this on just your top level parent Layout and that might work.

You could set your layout to be invisible with

```
yourParentLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

that will hide all of your UI elements which will make them not clickable.

One of those are probably your best bet I would think. There are non-public APIs that you can use to shut off and turn on the screen you can find them if you search around on here for turn screen off/on programatically.

I would also suggest if you want to and have the time find and look at the source code for the app that handles phone calls, it has the behavior you are looking for so you could probably use a similar method to them(though I've not seen this source, so its possible that they are using the non-public API to shut off and turn on the screen.)

As far as restoring your views after the phone moves away, you'll just have to add a check in your onSensorChanged() method that checks if the proximity sensor is no longer sensing a close object. If it isn't then undo whichever method from above you use to make your views unclickable.