# disable touch input in android programmatically

Tags: android, input, touch

I want to disable touch input in an activity during certain conditions. Is there any way to accomplish disable touch?

Comment: Can you please elaborate the 'certain' conditions? It might help.

Comment: By detecting proximity sensor. If proximity is near, then touch should   be disabled.

Comment: ^ Can you put that in question itself. Did you try using `view.setClickable(false);` for your outermost view or all the views that you have? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002849/disable-ui-in-my-activity-when-user-places-the-phone-near-his-her-ear is a similar question which "might" help.

Answer (score 2):

To disable touch events on an activity:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

To re-enable touch events:

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the view that you want to disable the touch inputs on and [setOnTouchListener(null)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnTouchListener%28android.view.View.OnTouchListener%29)

Answer (score -1):

```
    this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false)
```